# Visual Studio- SSRS- Use When Statement with Parameter

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, parameters

In the Select Statement, I have a Clause that looks at two different values based on the data in a column.  How can I use the same logic to display value A or B based on if the value is present or not from the Select Statement

SELECT Statement

```
ISNULL((CASE WHEN (x.USER_NAME_01 = NULL) THEN RTRIM(RIGHT(x.USER_NAME_01, 15))
      WHEN (x.USER_NAME_01 IS NOT NULL) THEN RTRIM(RIGHT(x.USER_NAME_01, 15)) END), RTRIM(RIGHT(APVENMAST.USER_NAME_01, 15))) AS 'Last 5 Digits of FAMIS Vendor Number'
```

Paramater - I tried something like this, but it didn't work

```
WHERE 
        (
        x.USER_NAME_01 = NULL THEN 
        @FAMISVendorID = RTRIM(RIGHT(x.USER_NAME_01, 15))
        )
    OR (
        x.USER_NAME_01 IS NOT NULL THEN 
        @FAMISVendorID = RTRIM(RIGHT(x.USER_NAME_01, 15))
        )
    ELSE   
       (
       @FAMISVendorID = RTRIM(RIGHT(APVENMAST.USER_NAME_01, 15))   
       )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood, there is an issue with the overall logic in the `SELECT` statement. You are trying to take the right 15 characters when x.USER_NAME_01 is NULL but it will never return anything.

That aside, the basic logic is something like this.. (you might have to adjust this, as I have only guessed what you were trying to do)

```
WHERE
    @FAMISVendorID = CASE 
                        WHEN x.USER_NAME_01 IS NULL THEN RTRIM(RIGHT(APVENMAST.USER_NAME_01, 15)) 
                        ELSE RTRIM(RIGHT(x.USER_NAME_01, 15))
                    END
```